# Combining two arrays in JavaScript with for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, for-loop, element

I would like to know if there is a smarter way to 
1) declare the two arrays, especially the numbers one (possibly with the dot operator?), and 
2) combine the string elements of these two arrays into a third without using an old fashioned for loop, perhaps with Array.map() or Array.from()?

```
const letters=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
const numbers=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

const combined=[]

for (let i=0; i < letters.length; i++)
{
    for (let j=0; j < numbers.length; j++)
    {
        combined.push(letters[i] + numbers[j]);
    }
}

// output a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, b1...
```

Comment: That looks perfectly fine to me (except for the `new Array` parts, and the implicitly global `i` and `j`s). I don't think any other approach is more performant than what you're doing currently. I'd prefer `forEach` or `for..of` over `for`, but that's a miniscule improvement

Comment: @CertainPerformance How are they global? Sorry for the beginner question, I am just wondering why I should use other iterator variable names? And could you also elaborate why I should not use new and instead var letters=["a", "b", "c", "d"]; Thanks!

Comment: @CertainPerformance Does "Smarter way" mean "more performant"? I think he is just looking for a "smarter" approach, if we can talk about "smarter" here, since it would imply reading a single line of code or so.

Comment: Are `letters` and `numbers` arrays part of the input or you want to create them dynamically as well?

Comment: @user2768479 - They're global because you haven't declared them, so your code is falling prey to what I call (on my anemic little blog) [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Comment: Your code works, finding a "more elegant" way is simply an opinion based question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) declare the two arrays, especially the numbers one (possibly with the dot operator?)

You mean *create* rather than declare (you don't declare arrays in JavaScript, because it's a loosely typed language). Yes, you can use an array literal:

```
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
```

or `split`:

```
var letters = "abcd".split("");
```

...though whether `split` is "smarter" is a matter of opinion. :-)

You can also use the mapping feature of [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
var letters = Array.from(Array(4), (_, index) => String.fromCharCode(97 + index));
```

But that might be a bit overdoing it. It makes more sense for the numbers one as you mentioned:

```
var numbers = Array.from(Array(6), (_, index) => index + 1); // Note I've renamed it to be plural
```

> 2) combine the string elements of these two arrays into the combined one without using an old fashioned for loop, perhaps with Array.map() or Array.from()?

A `for` loop is simple and clear, but [`for-of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) would probably be even simpler and clearer:

```
for (const letter of letters) {
    for (const number of numbers) { // Note I've renamed the `numbers` array to be plural
        combined.push(letter + number);
    }
}
```

Although you could shoehorn it into an `Array.from` by doing math on the index, to me it would be overcomplicated.

---

`for-of` and `Array.from` are both new(ish) as of ES2015 (aka "ES6"), so be sure to check your target environments for support, and/or use transpiling (for `for-of`) and a polyfill (for `Array.from`).

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, a `for` loop is perfectly adequate. If you want to use something like `.map()` though, you can do something like this:

```
var letters=new Array("a", "b", "c", "d");
var numbers=new Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
var combined=new Array();

// Map array
letters.map(letter => {
  for(let number of numbers) combined.push(letter + number)
});

// Log output
console.log(combined); // -> "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "b1", "b2", "b3", ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with nested loops (which of course should be `for..of`, not `for`), but if you want a "functional" solution, consider [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
let letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
let numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];

let combined = letters.flatMap(a => numbers.map(n => a + n));

console.log(combined);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce function:

```
letters.reduce((a,b) => {
   a.push(...number.map(n => b + n));
   return a;
}, [])
```

This should give desired result

```
["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5", "b6", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tis is the one-liner you need -:

```
let result = letters.reduce((comb, item, key) => comb.concat(numbers.map(i => (item+i))), []);
```

```js
var letters=new Array("a", "b", "c", "d");
var numbers=new Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
let result = letters.reduce((comb, item, key) => comb.concat(numbers.map(i => (item+i))), []);
```

Answer (score -2):

Sorry but there is a typo error in your code. You wrote 'number' instead of 'numbers' when defined the variable.

```
var letters=new Array("a", "b", "c", "d");
var numbers=new Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
var combined=new Array();

letters.forEach(letter => {
    numbers.forEach(number => {
        combined.push(letter + number);
    }
});
```